# no internet connection on QNAP NAS - How to troubleshoot?

Tags: nas, internet-connection, qnap

My power fell out a couple of times past week, and today I logged into my NAS to double check the file system for errors.
My system was checked and fine but I have **no more internet**.

- NAS model: QNAP TBS-453DX
- firmware version: 4.4.2.1320

I'll give some background and some SSH commands I tried:

1. The IP address had changed apparently from `192.168.1.6` to `192.168.1.3`.
2. Via Qfinder on macOS I changed it back to fixed `192.168.1.6`, after that I realised I had no internet.
3. I double check my router page, and under the LAN address management it still said `192.168.1.3` next to my NAS name.
4. I try to change the NAS back to: "Obtain IP address settings automatically via DHCP" after which it goes back to the `192.168.1.3` IP address.
5. still no internet though.

I SSH into the NAS and ran these commands:

```
[~] # ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (172.217.27.68): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: Network is unreachable
```

and

```
[~] # route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.0.3.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 lxcbr0
10.0.5.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 docker0
127.0.0.0       *               255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

and

```
[~] # nslookup qnap.com
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   qnap.com
Address: 54.236.152.254
Name:   qnap.com
Address: 52.73.74.127
```

and finally

```
[~] # ifconfig
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 06:BE:53:BE:70:6E
          inet addr:10.0.5.1  Bcast:10.0.5.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11638 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:1172174 (1.1 MiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 24:5E:BE:43:A8:0D
          inet addr:192.168.1.3  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::265e:beff:fe43:a80d/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 240d:1a:3ff:1500:265e:beff:fe43:a80d/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:910735 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:668965 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:303881310 (289.8 MiB)  TX bytes:260874678 (248.7 MiB)
          Memory:a1600000-a161ffff

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 24:5E:BE:43:A8:0E
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:974126 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:974126 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:335475891 (319.9 MiB)  TX bytes:335475891 (319.9 MiB)

lxcbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 16:E4:17:61:31:61
          inet addr:10.0.3.1  Bcast:10.0.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12075 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:1242393 (1.1 MiB)

veth619e958 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 06:BE:53:BE:70:6E
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7988 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:691721 (675.5 KiB)
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Did you set a default gateway when manually setting the IP address?

Comment: @SamForbis thanks I found the issue, the DNS server address was wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was that I needed to enable "Obtain DNS server address automatically".

This was (somehow) set to **"Use the following DNS server address: 0.0.0.0"** which is wrong.

[image]